# Wildcard or RegEx in AzureDataFactory Dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to use WildCard OR RegEx for File Path in AmazonS3 type Dataset with "Key" Property. But it's not working

Let's Say I have FileName like 01-testdatafile_2017-03-13.tsv.gz in which 2017-03-13 will be produced via {0:yyyy-MM-dd} but the prefix can be any 2 digits. I tried below options but none of them worked!!

```
"$$Text.Format('data/*-testdatafile_{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.tsv.gz', SliceStart)"

"$$Text.Format('data/??-testdatafile_{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.tsv.gz', SliceStart)"

"$$Text.Format('data/[0-9][0-9]-testdatafile_{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.tsv.gz', SliceStart)"
```

Does RegEx/Wildcards are supported in ADF? Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this very much like it is for Azure Blob Stores and WildCards can only be used in the file-filter. Read the blog-post below for more information
http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2015/07/07/partitioning-and-wildcards-in-an-azure-data-factory-pipeline/